# How can I connect to network in Debian through the bridge?

Tags: wireless-networking, virtualbox, internet, debian

I'm Trying to connect to internet. I have Virtual Box and Debian in it.

I'm not able to do it.

When I try ifconfig

```
lo Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
...
```

Thought in /etc/network/interface I have

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopface

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.1.18
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

To etc/init.d/networking restart

```
siocsifaddr no such device 
eth1:  ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
SIOCSIFNETMASK: no such device 
eth1:  ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

ifconfig -s prints

```
iface MTU Met RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR FLG
lo       16436 0    696      0       0 0        696       0   0       0    L
```

Can somebody help me please. Thank you in advance

Comment: What does `ifconfig -s` output?

Comment: That's all? No network devices are listed at all? At least the loopback device `lo` should be mentioned, otherwise there is something seriously wrong with your setup.

Comment: The kernel seems not to detect your network hardware. Do you find the device in the output of `lspci` or `lsusb`? Does `dmesg|grep eth` output something related?

Comment: @Macro Thank you very much, I solved my problem. :)